# Who has to do the Data Model design

Tags: data-modeling

please clarify me on the below questions,
   who will do the great data model design?
     Technical lead / Database Admin

Thanks,
Gunasekaran Sambandhan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how the responsibilities on your team are broken out. Normally, I would say the Technical Lead (Application Architect) would do the data model design. The DBA could then implement and tune the database to provide the best performance.

That could always changed based on the skills of the Technical Lead and the DBA though...

Comment: thanks justin, 
Am confident in domain, but not so good in database design. Will it work by combining the knowledge of DBA and Tech lead

Comment: It should. You know what your application needs, and the DBA should be able to provide some guidance on how the data could best be designed for storage and performance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how large your team is and how well its structured. In data-centric applications I can tell you that as technical lead I have generally done either the database design or a high-level version that is refined (and sometimes changed a lot) by a dedicated database developer.

But there is no hard and fast rule.